# Highcharts donut label overflow container

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting to create a donut chart with (long) labels. The container for the chart is small (and dynamic). I keep running into a problem where the labels for the outer chart are cutoff.

```
            series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData,
            size: '65%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: 'white',
                distance: -30
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData,
            size: '85%',
            innerSize: '65%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                }
            }
        }]
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw99B/

What I am trying to accomplish is the auto pie size, as is the case with simple pies:

```
            series: [{
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData,
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                }
            }
        }]
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4P4D5/

The problem with donuts is that I have to specify the size of the inner & outer donut. This causes the two pies making the donut to have fixed radius. Ideally, I would have the inner pie be a percentage of the outer; and let the outer pie have an auto-size.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following minor patch to `highcharts.src.js` v4.0.1 achieves the desired behaviour:

```
    --- highcharts.src.orig.js  2014-04-24 08:25:52.000000000 +0000
    +++ highcharts.src.js   2014-06-24 13:57:42.957605307 +0000
    @@ -12167,6 +12167,22 @@
                positions = [pick(centerOption[0], '50%'), pick(centerOption[1], '50%'), options.size || '100%', options.innerSize || 0],
                smallestSize = mathMin(plotWidth, plotHeight),
                isPercent;
    +
    +       /**
    +        * Allow a chart (pie) to specify a size relative to another series. In
    +        * that case, simply copy the center position of the parent, and scale
    +        * the radius.
    +        */
    +       if ( options.relativeSize ) {
    +           parentPositions = chart.series[options.relativeSize.parentSeries].center;
    +           positions[0] = parentPositions[0];
    +           positions[1] = parentPositions[1];
    +           positions[2] = options.relativeSize.size * parentPositions[2];
    +
    +           return map(positions, function (length, i) {
    +               return positions[i]
    +           });
    +       }

            return map(positions, function (length, i) {
                isPercent = /%$/.test(length);
```

Then, when configuring the donut:

```
            series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData,
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: 'white',
                distance: -30
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData,
            relativeSize: {
                parentSeries: 0, // index of parent series
                size: 0.75       // 75% of parent pie
            }
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? ''+ this.point.name +': '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                }
            }
        }]
```

Note that the parent (outer) pie must be explicitly centered in the container, otherwise in certain cases the two pies may not be concentric.

Also, requiring the index of the series to be specified is clearly not ideal, but in a tightly controlled graph (as is a donut), it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The `dataLabels: formatter...` is only controlling whether or not to show datalabel for thinner slices.  It's not controlling the size of the pie chart.  That is being specified by the `series:[{size` parameter.  In your example it's set to 85% of the container which does lead to overflow.

According to the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size)

> The default behaviour (as of 3.0) is to scale to the plot area and
>   give room for data labels within the plot area.

If you [comment out the size on your example](http://jsfiddle.net/sw99B/1/), it does indeed squeeze in the labels but I'm not sure you'll love the look of it.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Indeed, that is the outcome I was trying to avoid. I like that the "outer" slices are resized automatically. What I need to accomplish is make the "inner" pie also resize based on the scaled "outer" pie. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not available, so I advice you to post your request on the [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)